# GraphQL project structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

What is the best way to structure a graphQL project/server side? 
this is my current structure

- src
- config
- models
- setup
- schema

  - queries

    - index
    - userQuery
  - resolvers

    - index
    - userResolver
  - types

    - index
    - userType

Comment: Looks good! And, [here's another example](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-yoga/blob/master/examples/modular-resolvers/README.md) that's similar, I think 

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think there is **the best** way to structure a GraphQL server. Your seems fine!

Check this [GraphQL APIs repo](https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-apis) that contains several examples and repositories with many different implementations.

In my TypeScript projects I usually use a structure like this:

```
src/
├── user/
│   ├── data.ts
│   ├── mutation.ts
│   ├── query.ts
│   └── type.ts
├── bananas/
│   ├── data.ts
│   ├── mutation.ts
│   ├── query.ts
│   └── type.ts
├── utils/
│   ├── database.ts
│   └── config.ts
├── index.ts
└── schema.ts
```

Comment: What do you handle in `data.ts` files?

Comment: @jastor_007 it is just functions to handle data request/response from database.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Hi, how you connect all mutation and queries in single file?

Comment:   @Dan, I connect them all in the `schema.ts` file. Here I have a very old example I made, it still shows the idea: https://github.com/MarcoDaniels/graphql-demo/blob/master/services/API/src/Schema.ts

Answer (score 7):

```
src
  schema
     Product
        model.js
        query.js
        mutation.js
        type.js
        resolvers.js
        index.js
     Order
        query.js
        mutation.js
        model.js
        types.js
        resolvers.js
        index.js
     index.js
```

***let's explore what's inside the Product directory***

**query.js**: all the query resolvers related to the Product

**mutations.js**: all the mutation resolvers related to the Product

**types.js**: all the Product related GraphQL types also query and mutation included (export a string containing GraphQL types).

**mode.js**: the Product database schema.

**resolvers.js**: all the resolvers related to the Product type.
e.g:

```
let Product = {
    comments: (user: id) => {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

**Product/index.js**: combine all the files and export them as *Query*, *Mutation*, *types*, *Product* (Product type fields resolvers).

***Note:*** you can also convert query.js or any one of them to a folder and then write each query and mutation resolver in its own file.

**schema/index.js**: combine all the exported *Query*, *Mutation*, *type* inside index.js and export them as *resolvers* and *typeDefs*

e.g

```
export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      ...ProductQueries,
      ...OrderQueries,
    },
    Mutation: {
      ...ProductQueries,
      ...OrderMutations,
    },
    // schema/Proudct/resolvers.js
    Product,
    Order
}
```

For a complete description follow this link
https://theehsansarshar.hashnode.dev/scalable-graphql-architecture

Answer (score 0):

I have created the simplest GraphQL TypeScript project with a standard folder structure. You can refer to.

https://github.com/JayeshGatkal/typescript-graphql-demo

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30419260)